# Testing reactivemongo with scalatest raise an exception

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to test some functionality in the app. I have other tests (with scalatest for reactivemongo) and are working, but with this I am getting this exception

> [info] - should Persist and find a token *** FAILED ***
>   [info]   The future returned an exception of type: reactivemongo.api.commands.bson.DefaultBSONCommandError, with message: CommandError[code=26, errmsg=ns not found, doc: {
>   [info]     ok: BSONDouble(0.0),
>   [info]     errmsg: "ns not found",
>   [info]     code: BSONInteger(26)
>   [info]   }]. (DaosApplicationSpecOneAppPerTest.scala:74)

This is the code for the tests (both are throwing the same error)

```
class UserTokenDaoMongoSpec extends DaosApplicationSpecOneAppPerTest {
  "UserTokenDao" should {
    "Persist and find a token" in withUserTokenDao { userTokenDao =>
      val future = for {
        _ <- userTokenDao.save(token)
        maybeToken <- userTokenDao.find(token.id)
      } yield {
        maybeToken.map(_ == token)
      }
      whenReady (future) { result =>
        result.get must be (true)
      }
    }

    "Remove a token" in withUserTokenDao { userTokenDao =>
      val future = for {
        _ <- userTokenDao.save(token)
        _ <- userTokenDao.remove(token.id)
        maybeToken <- userTokenDao.find(token.id)
      } yield {
        maybeToken
      }
      whenReady (future) { result =>
        result must be (None)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and for brevity, this is the method that inherits

```
def withUserTokenDao[T](t: UserTokenDao => T):T = running(app) {
  val userTokenDao = new UserTokenDaoMongo
  whenReady (userTokenDao.tokens.drop()) { result =>
    t(userTokenDao)
  }
}
```

The UserTokenDao implementation

```
class UserTokenDaoMongo extends UserTokenDao {

  lazy val reactiveMongoApi = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]
  val tokens = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("tokens")

  def find(id:UUID):Future[Option[UserToken]] =
      tokens.find(Json.obj("id" -> id)).one[UserToken]

  def save(token:UserToken):Future[UserToken] = for {
    _ <- tokens.insert(token)
  } yield token

  def remove(id:UUID):Future[Unit] = for {
    _ <- tokens.remove(Json.obj("id" -> id))
  } yield ()

}
```

and this is the model of UserToken

```
class UserTokenDaoMongo extends UserTokenDao {

  lazy val reactiveMongoApi = current.injector.instanceOf[ReactiveMongoApi]
  val tokens = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("tokens")

  def find(id:UUID):Future[Option[UserToken]] =
      tokens.find(Json.obj("id" -> id)).one[UserToken]

  def save(token:UserToken):Future[UserToken] = for {
    _ <- tokens.insert(token)
  } yield token

  def remove(id:UUID):Future[Unit] = for {
    _ <- tokens.remove(Json.obj("id" -> id))
  } yield ()

}
```

I am not sure what could be causing the error

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was that the collection *tokens* did not exist. I got into the mongo console, then I created the collection and the tests started working.

Comment: You can have a look at [fix #437](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/pull/437).